# Millisecond (and greater) precision for audio file elapsed time in iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudioplayer, audiounit

I am looking for a low-latency way of finding out how many seconds have elapsed in an audio file to guaranteed millisecond precision in real-time. According to the [AVAudioPlayer class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/deviceCurrentTime), a call to `-currentTime` will return "the offset of the current playback position, measured in seconds from the start of the sound", however an `NSTimeInterval` is a `double` and this implies fractions of a second are possible.

As a testing scenario, I have an audio file playing and the user taps a button. Playback DOES NOT pause/stop, but at the moment the button was tapped I would like to obtain information about the elapsed time. In the real application, the "button may be pressed" many times in one second, hence the need for millisecond precision.

My files are stored as AIFF files and are around 1-10 minutes in length. Ideally I would like to find out exactly which sample frame is 'up-next' when playback resumes - however, this level of precision is a little excessive and millisecond precision is perfectly acceptable.

Is AVAudioPlayer's `-currentTime` method sufficient to achieve guaranteed millisecond precision for a currently-playing audio file? Or, would it be preferable to use a lower-level API such as iOS's Audio Units?

Comment: Consider this -> http://theamazingaudioengine.com/

Comment: Or this -> https://github.com/sbooth/SFBAudioEngine

Comment: What is your precise reference point for mS elapsed time?  (Note that the undocumented iOS OS latencies may be a magnitude larger in time: including touch events, GPU/graphics frame rate, driver+hardware audio buffering, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want sub-millisecond relative time resolution, convert to raw PCM and count buffers * length + samples using a low latency RemoteIO Audio Unit configuration.  Most iOS devices will support as small as 6 mS RemoteIO buffers of 256 samples, with a callback for each buffer.